# What is the meaning of Beth Aven (בית און)?

Tags: hebrew, joshua, etymology

in Joshua 7:2 are EL (אל) and AVEN (און) used in contrast to each other.

> וישלח יהושע אנשים מיריחו העי אשר עם־בית **און** מקדם לבית־**אל** ויאמר אליהם לאמר עלו ורגלו את־הארץ ויעלו האנשים וירגלו את־העי׃

in English

> Joshua sent men from Jericho to Ai, which is near Beth-**aven**, east of Beth **el**, and said to them, “Go up and spy out the land.” And the men went up and spied out Ai.

Obviously El(אל) is a divine name I have not found a biblical us of Aven(און) that is not in reference to this place. If you look at the Hebrew they form a sort of visual pun.

Are there any other examples of these two words being used this way?

I am also interested in non-place name uses of the word און.

Emptiness, wickedness, naughtiness, nothing have all come up as meanings but without etymology.

Comment: http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H205&t=KJV

Comment: "House of Iniquity," "House of Wickedness"

Comment: THank you MR. Hammer your link was helpful. What is your take on the use of Aven in Hosea?

Answer (score 2):

Non place uses:

[Bamidbar 23:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9951#v=21)

[Shmuel I 15:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15844#v=23)

[Yeshayahu 1:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15932#v=13)

[Yeshayahu 29:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15960#v=20)

[Yeshayahu 31:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15962#v=2)

[Yeshayahu 32:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15963#v=6)

[Yeshayahu 55:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15986#v=7)

[Yeshayahu 59](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15990) (three uses in 4,6 and 7)

[Yechezkel 11:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16109#v=2)

[Hoshea 6:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16160#v=8)

Comment: Hello, can you explain what is the significance of each of these verse citations? In other words, can you provide some narrative discussion of what I am seeing as I click each link?

Comment: Fantastic thank you so much. 
do you have any opinion on it being a visual pun?

Answer (score 1):

A great resource to use for these kinds of endeavors is BlueLetterBible.org. Here is the entry for [Beit Aven (H1007)](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H1007&t=KJV)

> Beth-aven = "house of vanity"

and the entry for [אָוֶן aven (205)](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H205&t=KJV):

> From an unused root perhaps meaning properly, to pant (hence, to exert oneself, usually in vain.
>
> Outline of Biblical Usage
>
> - trouble, wickedness, sorrow
>
>   ```
>   -trouble, sorrow
>
>   -idolatry
>
>   -trouble of iniquity, wickedness
>   ```
>
> (...) specially used of the vanity of idols.